# Does searching for my info expose my info?

Tags: email

My bank does a 'dark web' search on my email address to see if it's out there. It occurred to me that they might be *putting* my email address on the dark web by searching for it.

What stops the websites they're crawling from capturing the search string, extracting the email addresses, correlating them to the source of the query, and compiling a list of known good email addresses belonging to specific institutions based on an activity designed to protect from exactly that?

Answer (score 4):

You assume that the search happens by giving the website your details. It would be more efficient for large volume of searches to scrape all the data, then look for your details offline.

But, what your bank does and how they do it is up to them. It is of course possible for anything entered into a malicious site's search function to be logged.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Makes a lot of sense to get the data then search in a controlled environment.